# Error: The argument type 'Duration?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Duration' because 'Duration?' is nullable and 'Duration' isn't

Tags: flutter

How to, solve this?
Error: The argument type 'Duration?' can't be
assigned to the parameter type 'Duration' because 'Duration?' is nullable and 'Duration' isn't.

- 'Duration' is from 'dart:core'.
  toastDuration: duration,
  ^

Comment: Can you share your toast completely?

Comment: As for the error message it is saying the current data type of yours is nullable.

You can provide default value on null case

Answer (score 1):

if you're sure that it's not `null` just cast it like this :

```
Duration? durationExample = Duration(seconds: 2);
methodCallExample(durationExample as Duration);
```

or set an alternative when it's `null` :

```
Duration? durationExample = Duration(seconds: 10);
methodCallExample(durationExample ?? Duration(seconds: 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade flutter and dart to solve the issue